# Hot reload using Electron and Angular

Tags: angular, electron

I'm using Angular and Electron for my app.
I'm looking for a way to enable hot reload...
When I run my `yarn run electron` (scripts : `"electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && electron ."`), if I save a change, my app isn't reloading.
Here is my main.js file :

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");

let win;

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });

  // load the dist folder from Angular
  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true
    })
  );

  // The following is optional and will open the DevTools:
  // win.webContents.openDevTools()

  win.on("closed", () => {
    win = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

// on macOS, closing the window doesn't quit the app
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

// initialize the app's main window
app.on("activate", () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

I tried to include `require('electron-reload')(__dirname);` in the main.js file but nothing changed

Comment: _"change a save"_ did you mean _"save a change"_?

Comment: Also, are you trying to do a hard-reset (restart the electron main.js process) or a soft-reset (restart the BrowserWindow renderer processes)

Comment: Yes sorry I edited.
I don't really know, i'm new to electron, i'm trying to hot reload as Angular do.. I guess it's a soft reset, isn't it ?

Comment: Well are you expecting changes to your main.js file to cause a reload? If you are that would require a hard-reset. If you aren't worried about changes to your main.js file (i.e. you're okay with manually restarting the app by killing it then starting it again) then you can do with a soft-reset

Comment: I'm not worried about doing a hard-reset. Indeed, I want to reload when there is a change in my Angular components and the main.js.
How to do so ?

Comment: I'll write up an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this : https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron
It's an empty project template, using Electron and Angular.
Execute `yarn start` allow the hot reloading.
It's well written in the README.md !

Comment: Although this is worth looking at, it doesn't help to directly solve the issue for already existing projects.

Comment: It works very well! It may not be an exact solution for the question asked, but having something that works - and works well - is a great starting point to fixing the original question. I'm in the exact same position as the original poster and I'm going to start with this template and integrate my existing code into it. Thanks for the link, Clément.

Comment: It looks like you can just take the src directory from an existing project and replace the src directory of the template with that. The only other thing you would have to do is add the dependencies to package.json

Answer (score 4):

[`electron-reload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-reload) by default only reloads the `WebContents` of all open `BrowserWindows` when a file changes. If you want to restart Electron (i.e. if you want changes to the Electron main process file to reload the application), then what you're looking for is a "hard reset".

To do this you'll have to set the electron app path, like so:

```js
require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
    electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd')
});
```

The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-reload) says that the path should be to `./node_modules/.bin/electron`, but I've only been able to get it to work using `./node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd`. This is apparently [an issue with Windows machines](https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-reload/issues/26), and supposedly pointing to the executable works on MacOS. This may also be the case on Linux systems.

The following should be all the files you need for a boilerplate example:

<sub>**./main.js**</sub>

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
    electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd')
});

let mainWindow = null

function main() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()

    mainWindow.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        })
    )

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', main)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (mainWindow === null)  {
        main()
    }
})
```

<sub>**./index.html**</sub>

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

<sub>**./package.json**</sub>

```json
{
    "name": "electron-hot-reload-boilerplate",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "An Electron Boilerplate demonstrating hot reloading",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron ."
    },
    "repository": "https://github.com/link/to/your/repo",
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "You",
    "license": "CC-BY-SA-3.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "electron": "^3.0.9",
        "electron-reload": "^1.3.0"
    }
}
```

Install with:

```
> npm install
```

Run with:

```
> npm start
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried on Windows and when I save a change on my angular component, i got a white page...

Answer (score 1):

Isn't [app.relaunch()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprelaunchoptions) the way to go to perform a "hard reset"?

> `app.relaunch([options])`
>
> - `options` Object (optional)
>
>   - `args` String
>   - `execPath` String (optional)
>
> Relaunches the app when current instance exits.
>
> By default the new instance will use the same working directory and
>   command line arguments with current instance. When `args` is specified,
>   the `args` will be passed as command line arguments instead. When
>   `execPath` is specified, the `execPath` will be executed for relaunch
>   instead of current app.
>
> Note that this method does not quit the app when executed, you have to
>   call `app.quit` or `app.exit` after calling `app.relaunch` to make the
>   app restart.

Comment: The question askes how to use `electron-reload` which is a package that monitors files in a directory for changes and restarts the application when changes are made. `app.relaunch` is just a method to relaunch the app, it doesn't monitor any files. So no, this does not in any way answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's very late but thought this would be helpful for someone new landing on this page with issue.

Simply replace win.loadFile("path to index file of angular app"); with below code

```
if(env==="PROD"){
   win.loadFile("path to index file of angular app");
}else{      //// Else block is for hot reload in dev mode
   win.loadUrl("http://localhost:4200")
}
```

in electron main file. After this run your angular app with --live-reload option and then run electron app separately or create a script in package.json as given below

`ng serve --live-reload && electron .`

Answer (score 0):

change your code like i do:

and call reloadWindow method Wherever you need.

following this url : https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winreload

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

let mainWindow;
app.on('ready', Start);

function Start() {
  createWindow();
  settingsWindow();
}
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({ pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`), protocol: 'file:', slashes: true, }));
}
function reloadWindow() {
  mainWindow.reload();
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({ pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`), protocol: 'file:', slashes: true, }));
}
function settingsWindow() {
  mainWindow.maximize();
  mainWindow.setMenu(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me:

- install `electron-reload` simply by `npm install electron-reload`
- add these lines to your `main.js`

```
const electron = require('electron')

require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
    electron: require("${__dirname}/node_modules/electron")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've found is using [electron-reloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-reloader), after installation, just paste the following code at the top of the entry `.js` file, and you're all set:

```js
const { app } = require('electron')

app.isPackaged || require('electron-reloader')(module)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Full HMR

Below solution show how to set up HMR which reload electron into current url

In `package.json`

```
...
"scripts": {
  "runElectron": "electron .",
  "ngBuildDevHmr": "ng build --watch --configuration dev  --optimization=false --build-optimizer=false",
  "hmr": "node electron/edit-package.js --dev && copy config\\env-dev.json electron\\env.json && cd electron && tsc --skipLibCheck && cd .. && npm run ngBuildDevHmr"
  ...
}
...
"devDependencies": {
  ...
   "electron-reload": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
}
...
```

And we run `npm i` (do not confuse `electron-reload` witch `electron-reloader` - this two are separate libraries). In `angular\electron\main.ts`

```
import { BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron';
...

if (!env.production) { // do it only if we not in production build
    // Hot module replacement - if detect file changes in electron directory then reload it (external tool will delete and create new /dist electron folder after file changes)

    require('electron-reload')(
        __dirname + '\\..', // directory to check (we must go outside ../project dir because it will be deleted and recreated (detection not occure))
        {
            electron: path.join(__dirname + '\\..\\..', 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron'), // path to electron executable
            //hardResetMethod: 'exit' // hard reset after changes detection
        }
    );
}

// this function will check condition periodically - as long as it's value is not true
const waitUntil = (condition, checkInterval=100) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (!condition()) return;
            clearInterval(interval);
            resolve(1);
        }, checkInterval)
    })
}

...
app.on('ready', createWindow);
...
function createWindow() {
    let angularIsReady = false;

    win = new BrowserWindow({...});
    ...

    ipcMain.on('appControl', (event, eventType) => {
       if(eventType=="isReady") {
         angularIsReady = true;
       }
       ...
    }

    if (!env.production) {
        win.webContents.openDevTools();

        // Below code is used to jump into old page after HMR (hot module replacement)
        // when directory /dist will be deleted (during code rebuild by external tool) - then this event will be fired (because page will be deattachet from its old /dist directory)
        win.webContents.on("did-fail-load", async function(e) {
            // read current (old) url before page reload
            let previousUrl =  win.webContents.getURL(); 
            
            angularIsReady = false;

            // first we need load index.html from fresh /dist (and wait for angular run)
            win.loadURL(`file:///${__dirname}/../project/index.html`); 
            
            await waitUntil(()=>angularIsReady );

            // when angular is ready, then angular routing works, ang we can set old page url
            win.loadURL(previousUrl);
        });
    }
```

Inside file `angular\electron\preload.ts` add

```
export type ContextBridgeApi = {
    ...
    appControl: {
        ...
        isReady: () => void; // when angular is loaded and run
    };
    ...
}

const exposedApi: ContextBridgeApi = {
  appControl: {
    ...
    isReady: () => ipcRenderer.send('appControl', 'isReady'),
}
```

And inside `angular\src\app\app.component.ts` in `ngOnInit` add

`window.electron.appControl.isReady();`

### How to run it

In one terminal to compile code after each change, run

`npm run hmr`

this command will rebuild (delete and create) `angular\dist\project` directory.  And in second terminal run electron by

`npm run runElectron`

it will automatically detect that /dist folder changes and reload it into current url.